# How is Multithreading different to Tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does it work by splitting workload between threads so that they are processed at once?

Or, do they works similarly to tasks where any idle time is utilized by other threads?

Not sure why Multithreaded programming improves performance in certain situations but not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread is an abstraction of CPU/cores. A Task is an abstraction of some work that needs to be done.

Some kinds of tasks can benefit from running on multiple CPU/cores. These tasks are typically what we call CPU bound (the thing that limits the speed is your CPU). Examples of this are calculating rays of light in a ray tracing engine

Some kinds of tasks are bound by other things (typically I/O). For example, downloading a webpage (more CPUs won't make it download faster).

A single thread is able to run multiple tasks concurrently by switching between multiple tasks during `await`. This is similar to how a CPU can run multiple threads.

The difference between threads and tasks is that threads are typically OS threads which are extremely heavyweight (expensive to context switch, use lots of stack memory etc). And tasks (green threads) are much lighter weight, faster switching, uses less ram.